# Get last updated value SQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following table structure..

```
emp_id  |  base_rate | base_sal | effective_on
1001      26.22        1200        2015-10-12
1001      26.00        1100        2015-11-12
1001      26.00        1100        2015-12-12
1002      18           1200        2015-10-12
1002      19           1100        2015-11-12
```

I need to find get the last updated `base_rate` with `effective_on` date for each `emp_id`

Like output ..

```
1001   26.00  1100 2015-11-12
1002   19     1100 2015-11-12
```

See, for `1001` `2015-11-12` is selected instead of `2015-12-12` which is latest as the `base_rate` is same and hence previously effective from `2015-11-12`

I have tried.. everything.. not able to find the exact query..

Comment: @vkp any solution will work..

Comment: @atulquest93 not really.  a window function wouldn't work on mySQL. where as it would work on Oracle. For Example Teja's answer will not work on mySQL but it would work fine on Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is simple and easy to understand.

```
1) Assign rank for all the effective dates in descending order by partitioning  
   for each employee.
2) Select all the required fields for the last updated effective date from the 
   inner query and display the result.

SELECT emp_id,base_rate,base_sal
  FROM
     (
       SELECT *,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY effective_on DESC ) AS rn
         FROM table
      ) 
  WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Good answer for RDBMS supporting window functions.

Answer (score 2):

One method is to generate a subset of employees with max effective on and join back to the base set..

In the below we generate set "B" with Emp_ID and ME (max effective) and then we join back to the entire data set in the table and use the columns emp_ID and ME to limit the data in the base set and return all columns we care about.

**Put in English:**
We generated a data set for all the employess with only their max effective date, and then joined this data set back to the base set to limit the data in the base set to only contain records for employees with their most recent effective_on date.

```
SELECT A.Emp_ID, A.Base_Rate, A.Base_Sal, min(C.Effective_On)
FROM Table A
INNER JOIN (SELECT emp_ID, Max(Effective_on) ME 
            FROM Table A 
            GROUP BY Emp_ID) B 
 on A.Emp_ID = B.Emp_ID 
and A.Effective_ON = B.ME
INNER JOIN TABLE C
  on C.Emp_ID = A.Emp_ID
 and C.Base_Rate= A.Base_rate
 and C.base_Sal = A.Base_Sal
GROUP BY A.Emp_ID, A.Base_Rate, A.Base_Sal
```

This is more or less database agnostic whereas a row_number and limit would not work on mySQL as it doesn't support window functions.

Comment: needed to prefix the select columns with the table alais as Emp_ID existes in both A and B aliases.

Comment: this is returning .. `2015-12-12` as effective_on date .. which can be done using max() ..

Comment: Adding an additional join should do it; along with some aggregation.

Comment: Because he's after the earliest effective on date, for the same emp_ID, base_rate and base_sal.  From question: "See, for 1001 2015-11-12 is selected instead of 2015-12-12 which is latest as the base_rate is same and hence previously effective from 2015-11-12"

Answer (score 1):

You can first get the minimum date each base_rate becomes effective on for every employee and then take the max from there.  Here is how you can do it using row_number() in oracle:

```
with temp(emp_id, base_rate, base_sal, effective_on)
as (select 1001,      26.22,        1200,        '2015-10-12' from dual union all
    select 1001,      26.00,        1100,        '2015-11-12' from dual union all
    select 1001,      26.00,        1100,        '2015-12-12' from dual union all
    select 1002,      18,           1200,        '2015-10-12' from dual union all
    select 1002,      19,           1100,        '2015-11-12' from dual
)

SELECT emp_id,base_rate,base_sal,effective_on FROM(
  SELECT temp2.*,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY effective_on DESC) AS rn2
    FROM
       (
         SELECT temp.*,
                row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID, BASE_RATE ORDER BY effective_on) AS rn
           FROM temp
        ) temp2
    WHERE rn = 1
  )
WHERE rn2 = 1;
```